# Unable to switch the screen page while consuming web service in android

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to consume this web service:
`http://54.251.60.177/TMSWebService/MarginService.asmx` in android by the method SOAP.

The input values for this web service is

```
fd : 01/01/2012
td : 07/07/2012
```

But I am unable to switch the screen page, can any one tell me what mistake I am committing here? Please let me know the solution..

Thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to consume the web service in an Activity, you should try using a Service instead so that the web service can be consumed off of the UI and then the UI can read from the persisted data in the service when it is ready. This way you can also switch pages during load and updates.

Comment: Actually i think i have done like what you have suggested...but i am unable to switch the screen

Comment: What do you mean unable to switch the screen? Like your intents fail?

Comment: No..i have checked it out,i guess its perfectly configured,but i cannot judge whats going wrong....